# java script issue on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
$invoiceUrl = $editPageUrl.'&amp;action=Sendeinvoice';

<form method="post" class="form-inline" style="display:inline-block;" action="<?php echo $invoiceUrl; ?>">
```

Problem is on form submit URL is not working for first entry.

for example i have five entry than URL will not work for first entry (Working correctly for rest of four entry).

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense. Please show more code. where your entry and how you handling your entry?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this

```
$invoiceUrl = $editPageUrl.'&action=Sendeinvoice';

<form method="post" class="form-inline" style="display:inline-block;" action="<?php echo $invoiceUrl; ?>">
```